# Opening a specific Tab which is inside a Fragment from NavigationDrawer in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer

I have implemented `NavigationDrawer` which has static types of items in it. And I have added `ViewPager` and `Tabs` in one of the many fragments. Everything is working fine till now. But now I want to open specific tabs and ViewPagers `onClick` of the items of that `NavigationDrawer`. I'm trying to set the current item and tab from the adapter class of the `NavigationDrawer` but not getting proper result.

TabsAdapter.java

```
public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    private final Context mContext;
    private final TabHost mTabHost;
    private final ViewPager mViewPager;
    private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

    static final class TabInfo {
        private final String tag;
        private final Class<?> clss;
        private final Bundle args;

        TabInfo(String _tag, Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
            tag = _tag;
            clss = _class;
            args = _args;
        }
    }

    static class DummyTabFactory implements TabHost.TabContentFactory {
        private final Context mContext;

        public DummyTabFactory(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            View v = new View(mContext);
            v.setMinimumWidth(0);
            v.setMinimumHeight(0);
            return v;
        }
    }

    public TabsAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, TabHost tabHost, ViewPager pager) {
        super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
        mContext = activity;
        mTabHost = tabHost;
        mViewPager = pager;
        mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void addTab(TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
        tabSpec.setContent(new DummyTabFactory(mContext));
        String tag = tabSpec.getTag();

        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(tag, clss, args);
        mTabs.add(info);
        mTabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTabs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
        return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);

    }

    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        int position = mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
    }

    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        // Unfortunately when TabHost changes the current tab, it kindly
        // also takes care of putting focus on it when not in touch mode.
        // The jerk.
        // This hack tries to prevent this from pulling focus out of our
        // ViewPager.
        TabWidget widget = mTabHost.getTabWidget();
        int oldFocusability = widget.getDescendantFocusability();
        widget.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
        widget.setDescendantFocusability(oldFocusability);
    }

    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }

}
```

Can anyone please help me in it?

Answer (score 1):

You are implementing **nested fragments**.

Can you try to replace your `activity.getSupportFragmentManager()` with `activity.getChildSupportFragmentManager()`.

Comment: When I replace `getSupportFragmentManager` with `getChildSupportFragmentManager`, it says `getChildSupportFragmentManager` cannot be resolved.

Comment: Your fragment must be extend from support library. Make sure you import support fragment.

Comment: Also you need to use AppCompatActivity or FragmentActivity

Comment: If I extend it with activity then it means its an activity not fragment. Right?

Comment: Right. It is an Activity which can use Support Fragment classes. So that you need also use Support Fragment for your fragments :)

Comment: But I'll have to do this inside a fragment not in activity.